Coupling identical Continuous-Time Markov Chains
In proving an irreducible positive recurrent CTMC $(X_t)_{t \ge 0}$, started in $\nu$, converges to its invariant distribution $\xi$, my lecture notes examine the coupled process of two independent copies of this chain. We start $\left(X^{(1)}_t\right)_{t \ge 0}$ in the distribution $\nu$, and $\left(X^{(2)}_t\right)_{t \ge 0}$ in the invariant distribution $\xi$. The process $\left( X^{(1)}_t, X^{(2)}_t\right)_{t \ge 0}$ is then stated without proof to be itself a CTMC, and furthermore to have invariant distribution $\eta_{(i,j)}=\xi_i \xi_j$.
They go on to claim that existence of this invariant distribution implies positive recurrence, and so we must in finite time reach a mixing state $(i,i)$ where these two agree - and the trick then is to construct a new chain started as $X^{(1)}_t$ but switched to $X^{(2)}_t$ at this time. This final construction is still, by the strong Markov property, $(X_t)_{t \ge 0}$ started in $\nu$, but can easily be shown to converge to the stationary distribution.
All this added in for completeness; I have some concerns about assuming positive recurrence from the existence of a stationary distribution without first guaranteeing non-explosivity, but overall that second paragraph is completely fine. The final stage of the first paragraph, however, seems to me to require more justification.
Particularly, I am struggling to demonstrate that the invariant distribution claimed is indeed correct. More generally, and arising from attempts at solving $\xi Q=0$, I am wondering what the transition rates of the coupled chain will be in terms of the rates $q_{ij}$ for  $(X_t)_{t \ge 0}$.

First, I assume the state space, say $E$, is countable since you are using indices $i,j$ to denote arbitrary states. This assumption is crucial for our discussion.
1. Positive Recurrence
An irreducible chain has to be either transient, null recurrent, or positive recurrent. If the chain either transient or null recurrent, there cannot be any invariant measure, leading to a contradiction.
2. The Coupled Kernel
The transition probabilities $q_{(i_1,i_2),(j_1,j_2)}$ of the coupled chain $(X^{(1)},X^{(2)})$ depend on its construction. If $X^{(1)}$ and $X^{(2)}$ are completely independent as you described, then
$$
q_{(i_1,i_2),(j_1,j_2)}=p_{i_1,i_2}p_{j_1,j_2},\qquad i_1,i_2,j_1,j_2\in E.
$$
Can you prove the invariance of $\eta=\xi^{\otimes2}$?
